# Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.1

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Getting the following error when creating a new Compose Project in Android Studio and updating to the suggested compose version of 1.2.1:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
> Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.2.1/compiler-1.2.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.2.1/compiler-1.2.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to compose version 1.2.0, and kotlin version 1.7.0.

The best way to figure out what versions you will need, is to go to the [compatibility guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

The version `androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.1` doesn't exist.
You can check it in the [google maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.compose.compiler:compiler)

[image]

You can in any case use the stable version of the module compiler `1.3.0` and all the other compose dependencies at 1.2.1:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.3.0'
        compose_version = '1.2.1'
    }
    //...
}
```

and then:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
   // stable 1.2.1 releases
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
   //... 
}
```

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) the compiler 1.3.0 requires kotlin 1.7.10: